# Why doesn't my welcome message work(discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to make a bot that gives a user member role and sends a simple welcome message to the chat. However when someone joins nothing happens(not even an error). Here is my code:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
        console.log(guildMember);
        let role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');
        guildMember.roles.add(role);
    
        member.guild.channels.get('channelID').send(`welcome <@${guildMember.id}> dont forget to 
        check the rules`);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you activate the necessary flags ? A client needs the following intent in order to get alerted when someone joins a server the bot is in

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({intents : ["GUILD_MEMBERS"]})
```

See more intents in [`the official documentation`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents)

In the end, it would look something like :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({intents : ["GUILD_MEMBERS"]})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
        console.log(guildMember);
        let role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');
        guildMember.roles.add(role.id);
    
        guildMember.guild.channels.get('the channel id')).send(`welcome <@${guildMember.id}> dont forget to 
        check the rules`);
    });
```

Also make sure you didn't put the `client.on('guildMemberAdd',...)` inside the `client.on('message',..)` They need to be separated.

Comment: I forgot to add the guild_members intent but now it gives an error when someone joins the server: TypeError: "899366272100339752".send is not a function

Comment: Well you are getting an ID, make sure it is a `Channel`

Comment: That's a different problem unrelated to the question. If this answer solved the related issue give it a checkmark